# NestedScrollView with Slivers Doesn't show AppBar on Scroll Up

Tags: flutter

I'm using NestedScrollView in order to achieve scroll show appbar gesture on myApp. Not sure what could be the issue, once scrolled down, doesnt show up again til you restart .

```
  body:  
        NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  floating: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  toolbarHeight: 80,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  bottom: 
                  PreferredSize(
                    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
                    child: new Offstage(),
                  ),
                 
                  elevation: 0,
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    // Icons
                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: 
          SafeArea(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                UserListPage(),
                MerchantListPage(),

              ],

            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. set `pinned: true,` inside **SliverAppBar()** widget refer NestedScrollView [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: NestedScrollView(
    floatHeaderSlivers: true,
    headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: const Text('NestedScrollView'),
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 200.0,
          forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
        ),
      ];
    },
    body: ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: 30,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Center(child: Text('Item $index')),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your result screen-> [image]